# Categorizing words in paragraphs into groups and assigning weights to them based on listed order

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, text-mining

I have a paragraph which contains names of at most 18 different industries. These names are separated by a semicolon. Their order of occurrence is also significant in determining their magnitude. Hence it has to be assigned as weights to the name. The list can be divided into 3 categories:

1. Industries that report growth. 2. Industries that report contraction. 3. Industries that report no change.

*Of the 18 manufacturing industries, 12 reported growth in January in the following order: Plastics & Rubber Products; Miscellaneous Manufacturing; Apparel, Leather & Allied Products; Paper Products; Chemical Products; Transportation Equipment; Food, Beverage & Tobacco Products; Machinery; Petroleum & Coal Products; Primary Metals; Fabricated Metal Products; and Computer & Electronic Products. The five industries reporting contraction in January are: Nonmetallic Mineral Products; Wood Products; Furniture & Related Products; Electrical Equipment, Appliances & Components; and Printing & Related Support Activities.*

The above paragraph is a sample. What is the best way to separate the text into 3 categories (2 in this case) and assigning values to them based on the listed order? A pattern occurs in the text. The names begin after ':' and end at '.'
Sometimes the names of Industries that report contraction are listed first followed by Industries reporting growth. How to overcome this while automating?

The value assignment would depend on the count of Industries in each category. The Industries reporting growth have positive values which decrease by 1 all the way to 1. The Industries without change have 0 as default value and the Industries with contraction have negative values whose magnitude decreases by 1 all the way to -1. These categories are then to be put together and sorted to get a list (+ve, 0, -ve) in decreasing order. Still in the early stage of programming. Please bear with me. Even suggestions of strategy to solve would help me go a long way.

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: I tried splitting the string by ';'. It gives a list of names. But not helpful with assigning values and categorizing into the 3 categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code that works for the example you gave, but I can't guarantee it will work on all samples you have (especially since you did not give an example with nochanges). The main idea is to specifically look for the terms 'growth', 'no change', and 'contraction' using regular expressions (`import re`) and then get the list of companies after each. Next each of the three categories is put through a list comprehension to get associated scores so that each list entry becomes a tuple of `(company, value)`. Finally the three categories are combined into one list, sorted by value (the 1st index), and printed out. Note that if the exact word 'growth' is not used, for example 'increase' is used in its place, this will not work.

CODE:

```
import re

sample = 'Of the 18 manufacturing industries, 12 reported growth in January in the following order: Plastics & Rubber Products; Miscellaneous Manufacturing; Apparel, Leather & Allied Products; Paper Products; Chemical Products; Transportation Equipment; Food, Beverage & Tobacco Products; Machinery; Petroleum & Coal Products; Primary Metals; Fabricated Metal Products; and Computer & Electronic Products. The five industries reporting contraction in January are: Nonmetallic Mineral Products; Wood Products; Furniture & Related Products; Electrical Equipment, Appliances & Components; and Printing & Related Support Activities.'

#Find the growth industries
growth_pattern = 'growth.*?:(.*?)\.'
growths = re.findall(growth_pattern,sample)
growths = growths[0].strip().split(';') if len(growths) == 1 else []

#Find the no change industries
nochange_pattern = 'no change.*?:(.*?)\.'
nochanges = re.findall(nochange_pattern,sample)
nochanges = nochanges[0].strip().split(';') if len(nochanges) == 1 else []

#Find the contraction industries
contraction_pattern = 'contraction.*?:(.*?)\.'
contractions = re.findall(contraction_pattern,sample)
contractions = contractions[0].strip().split(';') if len(contractions) == 1 else []

#Give numbers to each of the industries
growths = [(g.strip().replace('and ',''),len(growths)-i) for i,g in enumerate(growths)]
nochanges = [(nc.strip().replace('and ',''),0) for i,nc in enumerate(nochanges)]
contractions = [(c.strip().replace('and ',''),-(len(contractions)-i)) for i,c in enumerate(contractions)]

#Print them out to check (commented out for now)
#print('growths:'+str(growths))
#print('nochanges:'+str(nochanges))
#print('contractions:'+str(contractions))

#Combine them all together, sort by value, and print out
all_together = growths+nochanges+contractions
all_together = sorted(all_together,key=lambda x: -x[1])
print all_together
```

OUTPUT:

```
[('Plastics & Rubber Products', 12), ('Miscellaneous Manufacturing', 11), ('Apparel, Leather & Allied Products', 10), ('Paper Products', 9), ('Chemical Products', 8), ('Transportation Equipment', 7), ('Food, Beverage & Tobacco Products', 6), ('Machinery', 5), ('Petroleum & Coal Products', 4), ('Primary Metals', 3), ('Fabricated Metal Products', 2), ('Computer & Electronic Products', 1), ('Printing & Related Support Activities', -1), ('Electrical Equipment, Appliances & Components', -2), ('Furniture & Related Products', -3), ('Wood Products', -4), ('Nonmetallic Mineral Products', -5)]
```

Comment: Thank you. This is almost perfect for me. How to give option between 'is' and ':' ? When there is only 1 Industry in a category, they publish it without ':' and use just 'is'. Also, is there a way to search both words 'Growth' and 'increase' in the same code using | separating the two patterns?

Comment: Great, I'm glad my answer is close! I'll leave it up to you to fine tune the code for your needs. What you've asked for with regular expression `or` matching is entirely possible, and has already been answered on this site. If you feel that my answer is sufficient for your initial question please accept it. Good luck

Comment: Meanwhile, I tried sample = sample.replace(' is', ':') to tackle. Thank you again